# Dynamic variable cpp compilation

Tags: c++, compilation

I wish I could edit a variable in a .h file since compilation
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HOST (char *)"http://localhost/"
#define PATH "insert"
```

I want to edite `HOST` from compilation like this:

```
g++ -o output source.cpp -HOST http://mywebsite/
```

Comment: `g++ -o output source.cpp -DHOST='(char *)"http://localhost/"'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that with something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef HOST
  #define HOST (char*)"http://localhost/"
#endif

#define PATH "insert"
```

Then, on the command-line, you either specify `'-DHOST=(char*)"whatever"'` (and it will be used), or do not pass in any `-DHOST=` flag, and the default in the header will be used.

Comment: exactly the answer I needed! Thanks _O_